# Как сделать многоуровневый массив из элементов одноуровнего?

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$aSimple = array(30, 70, 150);
```

Какой конструкцией можно сделать из него многоуровневый массив используя значения $aSimple как ключи? Важно сохранить порядок ключей второго массива, как у значений первого.

```
$aMulti[30][70][150];
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$aSimple = array(30, 70, 150);
$out = array();
$cur = &$out;
foreach ($aSimple  as $value) {
    $cur[$value] = array();
    $cur = &$cur[$value];
}
$cur = null;
```

В `$out` будет нужный массив.

Comment: Спасибо. aSimple  в конструкции foreach без знака $. Такое же решение с array_map бы)